# How to PATCH and DELETE on Firebase using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React app with a Firebase database. I am able to POST and GET the items using push(), but Im not able to delete or patch anything to it. I have implemented a function which does .remove() on the proper child but it does nothing. Pretty new to Firebase so excuse if too newbie of a question..

I have all my firebase settings in a different firebase.js file. This is how Im trying to remove a child. Btw, doing a `console.log(serviceRef.child(this.state.domain))` does give me the right option as the 'key' is correctly related to the domain.

```
const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref('services');
serviceRef.child((this.state.domain)).remove();
```

EDIT: 
Here's my function that Im calling onClick. The binding and everything else has been done correctly.

```
deleteService = () => {
    const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref("services");
    let key;
    serviceRef
      .orderByChild("domain")
      .equalTo(this.state.domain)
      .on("value", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          if (childSnapshot.val().domain === this.state.domain) {
            console.log(childShapshot.key, childSnapshot.val());
            key = childSnapshot.key;
```

[image: Database Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to PATCH you want to look into the update method not the actual PATCH method. Since PATCH only updates the fields specified with the values given, UPDATE does the same thing in the case of the Firebase api.

```
const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref('services');
const data = {field: value};
// update the fields on the child
serviceRef.child(this.state.domain).update(data);
```

In order to delete, you can reference the same child and remove it from the list, but make sure you are using the correct key of the child.

```
const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref('services');
serviceRef.child(this.state.domain).remove();
```

Now you mentioned that when you remove, nothing gets removed from the Firebase database. When you console log the key of the fields you are searching for, is it the same as this.state.domain?

```
const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref('services');
console.log(serviceRef.child(this.state.domain).key);
```

Remember that Firebase will auto assign a randomly generated key upon pushing elements into the list. If you set up an index to look for in the rules for the database, this might be one reason why when you query using this.state.domain returns the document as your index is the documents field which matches the string you are passing, but this does not mean that the key of the document is the same.

If your key and the domain name are not the same then try something along the lines of:

```
const serviceRef = firebase.database().ref('services');
let key;
serviceRef.orderByChild('domainfield').equalTo(this.state.domain).on('value', 
  function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      if(childSnapshot.val().domannamefield === this.state.domain){
         console.log(childShapshot.key, childSnapshot.val());
         key = childSnapshot.key;
      }
  });

});
```

Keep in mind if you want to use orderByKey you want to set up rules for your database for indexing. By default your rules should look like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

In order to index the services collection by the domain field you want to update your rules in your database something like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,

    "services": {
      ".indexOn": ["domain"]
    }
}
```

Adding in the brackets [] next to .indexOn the columns in the child nodes of the collection you would want to index by.

Comment: When I do console.log on the child(this.state.domain), I do get a key as the domain name, however youre right that the key is not the same as the auto generated key by firebase.. I assumed that by key its gonna match the right entry and delete that instead.. Is there anyway for me to search for something like `where domain===this.state.domain` in the Firebase JSON?

Comment: I think your answer pretty much got me there, but im getting undefined on logging the key.. Is the domainNameField checking with the generate keys made by firebase or the actual fields inside each of those elements?

Comment: the field inside each of those elements. What is the field name where you store the domain name? domainNameField should be the field name of the domain  name inside the document.

Comment: Yup, thats what Im doing. I have a field name as domain and then im checking that with this.state. I already tried checking it with other field names but it still returns undefined :/

Comment: Ok check my updated comment, you will have to go through the child snapshots of the query you searched for. to retrieve the key

Comment: Is childSnapshot a firebase element? React says its undefined as ive obviously not defined it..

Comment: its a function parameter from the callback of the firebase query. Can i see a snippet of your code? Specifically where you are implemeting the function callback for the childsnapshot.

Comment: So ive implemented an onClick function where Im taking and removing the JSON. I did it using a fake server by using a DELETE and it worked fine but obviously Firebase is much different. Im putting the snippet as a question edit since I cant put everything here.. Its mostly the code you provided me here :)

Comment: Hey @Xavid, actually there was just a simple typo in the data.forEach function, that's why it was getting childSnapshot as undefined. I fixed it but now its not able to access this.state; I tried binding the forEach function but as I thought, it doesnt work either. I guess now I only need to figure out the binding inside the forEach function :)

Comment: Your code looks fine, just make sure you close the the brackets correctly. They are missing at the bottom of your code. Hopefully that resolves the childSnapshot is undefined. Unless it is undefined because there is no item that matches the search

Comment: Yess my bad about the closing brackets, missed it while copying.. Im just not able to bind the state inside of the data.forEach function even though Ive binded my deleteService.. How can I bind a function inside a function? Or maybe I should just put the query variable as another var instead of using my state directly?

Comment: Your state value should work inside the inner function as this.state.domain is at the top of the scope of the local function. What happens when you console.log the this.state.domain inside the innermost function call?

Comment: same error saying that it cant get state of undefined.. I tried putting the state value in a variable, so now I was able to get that working, however now I get `Query.equalTo failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'services` error.. Seems like its not able to get `serviceRef.orderByChild("domain")` as it did even in the last solution. You think I should just switch to another database instead? Not sure why REST calls are so troublesome. The "domain" field is the correct schema on my JSON objects too.

Comment: it would be easier if I could see the a sample structure of your data so I can properly assess why it is giving you undefined data.

Comment: Added in the Edit:)

Comment: can you manually place the value of this.state.domain rather than using it. I want to see if it at least queries the correct item, if it doesn't, so I can look at the query function. If it doesn't query it, there is an issue with this.state.domain being undefined when you are making the call to the database.

Comment: Yup but the problem im facing now is with the `serviceRef.orderByChild("domain")` This seems to be undefined in 'services' even though it should be able to grab domain right ? The state.domain does seem to have the correct value on whatever Im selected. Cant see why domain is being undefined.. I also tried putting '0' and '1' instead of domain to see if the keys would work but no luck..

Comment: Yes the inconsistent keys could be an issue, but make sure that in your database rules you have it set up to index by the field, look at my updated post.

Comment: Still no luck man.. It still gives me an undefined error for orderBy("domain").. There should be simpler way to search fro JSONs in Firebase right?

Comment: Can you export your json and put it on a pastebin so I can sample it into one of my firebase collections and test it out?

Comment: Don't know what else to tell ya this works perfectly fine. I put your json into my collections and ran this.  https://pastebin.com/N8c7h7HC

Comment: Wow that's weird! Anyways thanks a lot man! I started switching to a postgres today anyway so I think ill be fine :)